# Amazon cloud provisioning using puppet & theforeman

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

Does puppetlabs have modules to help provision for Amazon Ec2 instances within VPC / outside VPC? Any recommendations ?

I would like to launch an instance based on an AMI image. This instance should have multiple IP addresses attached to it. I would like to do this using theforeman.

Also, I noticed that theforeman documentation is lacking in EC2 area, so I am having quite a bit of issue setting it up multiple IPs on the Amazon instance. Would appreciate any help in this area?

Lastly, if I need to create files on the launched Amazon instance, how do I do it through theforeman? It seems that it is much easier to just do it using puppetmaster without theforeman....e.g.

```
file { "/var/log/admin-app-log":
    ensure => "directory",
    owner  => "root",
    group  => "wheel",
    mode   => 750,
}
```

I am still in the learning stage...therefore would appreciate some guidance. .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about theforeman.

Puppet does have a tool called the Cloud Provisioner. I haven't used it and I don't know if it works with VPC or not:

> https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2019.8/cloud_installing.html

Managing files through puppet is very easy and works well. You can ensure files are in place, copy a standard config file in from the puppet master, or even build a config using a template. Also you can do things like have services subscribe to their config files -- for example, having sshd restart automatically when sshd_config is updated. It's pretty slick and one of the things puppet is great at.